# Где ставить запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлена запятая:

Ведь никто ему не рассказал, почему она сказала те слова ему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формально правильно, запятая отделяет придаточное предложение от главного; но порядок слов необычный, оправданный разве что в стихах.

Обычный порядок слов:

**Ведь никто ему не рассказал, почему она сказала ему те слова.**